# How to insert into table in VB

Tags: sql, vb6

I want to insert into table some fields in VB. But it is not giving any result.

```
Dim a As String
a = s_up.Text1.Text
Dim b As String
b = s_up.Text2.Text
Set rs = Nothing
rs.Open "insert into profile (user_name,first_name) values(' " & a & " ',' " & b & " ' ) ", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Where is execute statement here

Comment: [You don't want to do it like that](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: if you have connection "cn" open then can you try 
cn.execute "insert into profile (user_name,first_name) values(' " & a & " ',' " & b & " ' ) "

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set up the ADO object earlier, setting it to `Nothing` before opening the result set probably isn't a good idea. Try removing this line to see if it helps. ie

```
Dim a As String
a = s_up.Text1.Text
Dim b As String
b = s_up.Text2.Text
rs.Open "insert into profile (user_name,first_name) values(' " & a & " ',' " & b & " ' ) ", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

oh yeh, and this approach isn't the most secure. Have a read up on best practices to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: I assume the recordset is declared `Private rs As New ADODB.Recorset`.

Comment: @trickwallett : didnt understood where are you executing statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL code does not return a resultset, so the result should be an instantiated recordset but with `State = adStateClosed`, so you won't be able to do much with it e.g. has no rows nor fields, can't be tested for RecordCOunt nor EOF, etc.